# MS Access: Resizing dialog form from within module

Tags: vba, ms-access, module, ms-access-forms

I am trying to open a form in dialog mode, and then resize it to a desired size using `DoCmd.MoveSize` from a module. Ideally I would like this all to run from said module.

Currently the form opens, but does not get resized. I am guessing this is either because the form is not yet active when the command is being run or because `acDialog` in the `OpenForm` command prevents it from being executed. I think I could get away with it plugging the `MoveSize` command into the `OnlOad` event of the form but I would prefer having as much of the functionality in the module instead. Is there some way around this issue? Like maybe there is some kind of method to wait for the form to be active or some way to plug a command into the `OnLoad` event from the module itself? As you can tell I am not too familiar with vba yet. It's part of a little project I am doing. Appreciate any help.

Some sample code is as follows:

*This one does not resize the form:*

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function OpenFormDialog()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "MsgBoxForm", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acDialog
    DoCmd.MoveSize , , , 9500
    
End Function
```

*This one throws an error because the form is not found:*

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function OpenFormDialog()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "MsgBoxForm", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acDialog
    Forms.("MsgBoxForm").DoCmd.MoveSize , , , 9500
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the form in normal mode, resize and make modal. Just make sure the Modal property on the form is No.

```
With DoCmd
    .OpenForm "MsgBoxForm", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acNormal
    .MoveSize , , , 9500
End With

Forms.MsgBoxForm.Modal = True
```

Keep in mind, any code below the last (modal) statement will still execute. If you need code execution to stop, your only option is to resize in the `Load()` event directly.

Personally, I believe the the `Load()` solution is better and you could pass the various sizes through the `OpenArgs` parameter.

Comment: Thx! If I want to pass more than one argument through OpenArgs (say width and height), which as I just read can only take one string, I will have to seperate them somehow in the string and then split the string up manually in the `Load` event? Or is there some other way? Can I declare some globals, use them in the `MoveSize` as arguments and set them to the values I want before loading the form in the module just before I call `OpenForm`? Or would that create issues?

Comment: The globals is a solution but best avoided. Concatenate the string, e.g. `10;20;30;40` and then split. Use the same format as the `MoveSize` for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the docmd.movesize in the form_open event of the MsgBoxForm form.

Additionally, by executing a docmd.openform, the control flow of program will transfer to the opened form and statements after the docmd.openform will not execute until the opened form is closed.

This is the reason MsgBoxForm is not in the forms collection after docmd.openform.

Comment: That works, but what would I need to do to change the specifics of the resizing from the module? I would like to be able to change the  size of the form when I am calling functionality from the module. Sometimes the form has to be larger or smaller and I would like to specify that whenever I open the form with a command. Can I make the arguments of MoveSize variables and expose them to the module, then set them before I call the OpenForm command?